# Power Automate update SP item where item has array

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I currently have two MS Sharepoint lists, where the first list has a lookup field to the second list. A user can use the lookup to select multiple choices.

I am then using Power Automate to update some of the other fields of the item, so have a Flow that is triggered when the item is initially created and then I try and update the item.

You can see the Update Item is giving me the 'Organisation Lookup id-1' field to populate - I cannot leave this blank.

If I set this to the dynamic properties then only the last Organisation Name is put back into the field rather than all of the picked values.

Eg

Original Organisation Lookup field: 'Amazon, Apple'

Results: 'Apple'

What should I use in this field to ensure the same original value is used as I do not want to change this field.

[image]

Comment: Firstly, if you’re updating an item, can you not put in the value by getting the existing value from the item as it currently stands? Secondly, that field you’ve highlighted is a single item, if it’s to be an array, you need to click on the icon to the right that looks like a T with a square around it, that will give you the ability to enter multiple items at once, ie an array.

Answer (score 0):

To update multiple selection lookup column, you can click on the T with a square around it shaped icon in lookup column at the right side.

Then you have to provide the data in below format:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 2
    },
   ...
]
```

Where `Id` is the item ID from parent list from where you have referenced the lookup column.

For more information, check: [How To Update Multi-value Lookup Column in SharePoint List using Power Automate](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302210/how-to-update-multi-value-lookup-column-in-sharepoint-list-using-power-automate)

Comment: thanks @ganesh unfortunately I do not know how many from the parent list there might be so I cannot use this method.

Comment: You can loop over the parent items and create a new array in required format. You can either using **Select** action or **Apply to each** action for this.